# Is it possible to get rid of template specialisation to stop recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I'm writing my own container class that also provides iterators. These iterators can be dereferenced and reveal then a sub-range of the original container, for which again an iterator can be obtained.

Currently, I've a template iterator class (using `boost::iterator_facade`) that dereferences to an `Collection` ("range") if `L!=0` or to a `T&` (stored elements) if `L==0`. Is it possible combine both in one class, such that less duplicate code is needed?

```
template<typename T, int L>
class CollectionIter : public boost::iterator_facade<
        CollectionIter<T,L>, // type it selfe
        Collection<T,L-1>, // value type
        boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
        Collection<T,L-1> > // deref. type
{
public:
    CollectionIter(T* ptr, const std::vector<int>& collectionSize_)
        : pointer(ptr), collectionSize(collectionSize_) { }
    T* element() { return pointer; }
private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    bool equal(const CollectionIter<T,L>& other) const { return pointer==other.pointer; }
    auto dereference() const { return Collection<T,L-1>(pointer, collectionSize); }
    void increment() { pointer = pointer + stepsize(); }
    void decrement() { pointer = pointer - stepsize(); }
    void advance(size_t i) { pointer = pointer + i*stepsize(); }
    auto distance_to(const CollectionIter<T,L>& other) { return (other.pointer - pointer)/stepsize(); }

    int stepsize() { return collectionSize.at(L); }

    T* pointer;
    const std::vector<int>& collectionSize;
};

/* Groundlevel Collection: deref returns T& */
template<typename T>
class CollectionIter<T,0> : public boost::iterator_facade<
        CollectionIter<T,0>,
        T,
        boost::random_access_traversal_tag >
{
public:
    CollectionIter(T* ptr, const std::vector<int>& collectionSize_)
        : pointer(ptr), collectionSize(collectionSize_) { assert(stepsize()==1); }
    T* element() { return pointer; }

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    bool equal(const CollectionIter<T,0>& other) const { return pointer==other.pointer; }
    T& dereference() const { return *pointer; }
    void increment() { pointer = pointer + stepsize(); }
    void decrement() { pointer = pointer - stepsize(); }
    void advance(size_t i) { pointer = pointer + i*stepsize(); }
    auto distance_to(const CollectionIter<T,0>& other) { return (other.pointer - pointer)/stepsize(); }

    int stepsize() { return collectionSize.at(0); }

    T* pointer;
    const std::vector<int>& collectionSize;
};
```

Comment: Without having a deeper look into your code, it looks as though you want to apply `std::conditional` somewhere in your code to avoid duplication and still get the inheritance right.

Answer (score 1):

I see only three differences in the two version of `CollectionIter`:

(1) the `boost::iterator_facade()` inherited class receive different arguments. You can solve this with `std::conditional` as suggested by Johannes Schaub; something like

```
   public std::conditional< (L > 0U),
              boost::iterator_facade<
                 CollectionIter<T, L>,
                 Collection<T, L-1U>,
                 boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
                 Collection<T, L-1U> >,
              boost::iterator_facade<
                 CollectionIter<T, 0U>,
                 T,
                 boost::random_access_traversal_tag > >
```

(2) the `assert(stepsize()==1);` in the constructor is present only in the ground (`L == 0U`) version. You can modify it as

```
assert( (L > 0U) || (stepsize() == 1) );
```

(3) the recursive `dereference()` method is really different in the ground version. I'm not an expert of SFINAE but, if I'm not wrong, you can insert both as follows

```
  template <int M = L, typename = std::enable_if_t<(M > 0U)>>
  auto dereference () const
   { return Collection<T, L-1U>(pointer, collectionSize); }

  template <int M = L, typename = std::enable_if_t<(M == 0U)>>
  T & dereference () const
   { return *pointer; }
```

So the full class become (sorry: I've changed `L` in a `std::size_t`)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t L>
class CollectionIter :
   public std::conditional< (L > 0U),
              boost::iterator_facade<
                 CollectionIter<T, L>,
                 Collection<T, L-1U>,
                 boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
                 Collection<T, L-1U> >,
              boost::iterator_facade<
                 CollectionIter<T, 0U>,
                 T,
                 boost::random_access_traversal_tag > >
 {
   public:
      CollectionIter (T * ptr, const std::vector<int> & collectionSize_)
         : pointer(ptr), collectionSize(collectionSize_)
          { assert( (L > 0U) || (stepsize() == 1) ); }

      T* element() { return pointer; }

   private:
      friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

      bool equal (const CollectionIter<T, L> & other) const
       { return pointer==other.pointer; }

      template <int M = L, typename = std::enable_if_t<(M > 0U)>>
      auto dereference () const
       { return Collection<T, L-1U>(pointer, collectionSize); }

      template <int M = L, typename = std::enable_if_t<(M == 0U)>>
      T & dereference () const
       { return *pointer; }

      void increment ()
       { pointer = pointer + stepsize(); }

      void decrement()
       { pointer = pointer - stepsize(); }

      void advance (size_t i)
       { pointer = pointer + i*stepsize(); }

      auto distance_to (const CollectionIter<T, L> & other)
       { return (other.pointer - pointer)/stepsize(); }

      int stepsize()
       { return collectionSize.at(L); }

      T * pointer;

      const std::vector<int> & collectionSize;
 };
```